# Parsing free-form date entry on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Is there a simple, established way to allow free-form date entry on a web page and parse the input text to get a Date value?    We have a new requirement to go from using a date picker to allowing free-form date entry.   So the user could theoretically enter any of the following:

```
12/7/41
12-7-1941
Dec 7, 1941
```

And we would have to attempt to parse it and make a date out of it.

I have attempted to find something online but the closest is this [JQuery widget](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Widget-For-Date-Entry-Validation-datetextentry/) which doesn't do the free-form thing.   There's also [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) but it looks unfinished and development stopped in 2008.   I'm just wondering if there's anything else out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MomentJS has what you are looking for. It's a robust library with almost all your time and/or date needs handled.
MomentJS Parsing: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers. - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ | Bottom line: use [String + Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/)

Comment: Thank you, this looks great.